# UML Class-Diagrams : class inheritance and relationships between classes

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I've never made a class diagram before, that's why I tried to ask. I always learn from my mistake. I have read some references, but I am confused how to test the results I made? because this is not a coding which if have error, the error message will be appear.

this my design database
[image: image1]

and this is a class diagram that I made based on design database.
[image: image2]

is the method for creating class diagrams similar to erd? I am very confused how to inherit the class and which arrow should I use?
in the path that I made there are three users. and each has a different role

1. Public Relations = Input data from external user (the applicant comes and gives a written proposal) then the data is stored in the database. The data includes applicant data and proposal data. PR can also see data that has been confirmed by the Division
2. Division = The division can see data that has been stored by PR and confirm the data. Data that has been confirmed will be filed and made a report.
3. Manager = can only see reports

Comment: Please bear in mind that this is no homework correction place. Your question as such is too broad. There are a couple of issues with your design. Try to be more specific in your question.

Comment: The problem statement _"public relations receives  ... have been made by division X."_ is very strange, it looks like an automatic translation. Check your inheritances,  for instance a User is not a Login so User cannot inherit Login, _Public Relations_ and _Division X_ cannot be by themselves a User (Person is probably a better name). Do not prefix the name of your attributes by the name of the class. The representation of the enumerations is very strange.

Comment: @ThomasKilian sorry, now I have updated my question.

Comment: @bruno please check my update, I just changed according to what you said.

Comment: Before you create a class diagram, determine its purpose. A class diagram is a model of 'something'. That 'something' can be a database, an application, the real world or anything else. What is it in your case? A model of the database?

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl Web-based Monthly Report Archiving sir. Is it already correct?

Comment: That's not what I mean. What is the purpose of the class diagram? Why do you want a class diagram? Who will use the diagram? What will they do with it? A possible answer is: "I want to make a class diagram for new developers who need to have an overview of the application before they dive into the source code."  or: "I want to make a class diagram for the software architect, who wants to have insight in the structure of the database and who demands to use UML as a standard."

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of findings:

- User->Login: This is no generalization. A user isn't a login. It might have some login information associated. So that shall be an association.
- Similar for Proposal->StatusProposal. But here it's a dependency since you will not create an enumeration object. You just use it to type an attribute.
- Same for User->Gender/RoleUser. Both are dependencies.

There are also a couple of design issues. But here YMMV too much. Having User implement userLogin() is at least questionable. There should be a security system taking care which validates a user login. So why does Login have a loginStatus()? However, design is not be discussed here.

As to class/ERD: they are similar, but not the same. UML has a broader scope while ERD focuses plainly on databases. So all the *_id attributes in your classes stem from a database design. The class design in that state is very much focused on databases. In a MDA it might be derived from a PIM to a PSM (so from an abstract view to a DB-specific one).

Comment: thanks, so i need remove object on status Proposal and change with dependency right? and also remove userLogin and statusLogin ?

Comment: I can't discuss the design issues without domain knowledge. Re. StatusProposal it's only the Generalization to be changed to a Dependency.

Comment: okay it's not a problem, it seems like I only have to delete it and the problem will be solved. Okay, I change the entire flow to the enum with dependency. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Thomas Killian's observations, your composition associations appear to be inaccurate. In effect, for example, you are specifying that the lifetime of a Department object is dependent on the lifetime of a User object. You are also specifying a whole-part relationship between Users and Departments, where the user is an aggregation of departments. I would think that it's the other way around. I also suspect that a user's lifetime isn't dependent on a department's lifetime, since a user can typically change departments. Therefore, an aggregation diamond (white) is probably correct, and it should be on the Department end.

Similarly, I have trouble making sense of your other two composition associations.

Comment: I just overlooked them. I almost never use composition for a couple of reasons. Mainly it's because lifetime dependencies tend to be superfluous except for security or memory management. People tend to over-use them, and wrongly too. Even worse when it comes to shared aggregation.

Comment: @ThomasKilian I agree that both forms of aggregation are overused, in that most associations between classes aren't whole-part relationships and are often diagrammed as such anyway. As for which to use when warranted, I usually imagine how a whole-part relationship will be implemented; if the whole will instantiate the parts, then I see it as composition, and if not then simple aggregation. Tom Pender gives the example of a car and its parts, where in a manufacturing context the parts will always be part of the car (once assembled), while in a junkyard context they won't.

Comment: Funny you take the car example ;-) I don't have Pender's bible (rev. 2003?)  but a quick google revealed https://slideplayer.com/slide/13019772/ where he uses the "old" composition definition which clearly does not match that of the current 2.5 specs. It looks like UML has some bad heritage here.

Comment: @ThomasKilian Interesting. I haven't taken a deep dive into the specs since I worked as a tech editor on the first edition of Tom's book. (Didn't know he made a revision; the first version came out a little while after UML 2.0.) Does the car example work in 2.5?

Comment: Not really. They boiled compositions rather down (see p. 110 of UML 2.5). And instead of introducing the dot-notation for owned properties I'd liked the composition diamond used for it, since basically that what everybody seems to use it for (and not a real live-time indicator). OTOH that would probably had introduced even more confusion.